# How to get tensorflow to evaluate shape at runtime?

Tags: python, tensorflow, linear-algebra, tensorflow-xla

I would like to evaluate the shape of a tensor at runtime. I am calculating the intersection between two sets. The number of intersections is the dimension of a tensor `x`. While defining the graph, the shape of the tensor is set to `[Dimension(None)]`. Thus, the usual `x.get_shape()` method will just return `None`. Is there a way to evaluate the shape `None` at run time? I could do `sess.run(x)` and get the shape of the numpy array, but I would like this to be a compiled op so that only the shape is returned. Thanks!

Comment: I do not understand, clearly. You mean, you want shape of a graph variable that already defined in placeholder and the shape of it has to be returned while session runs?

Comment: No, the tensor `x` is not defined as a placeholder but is the result of `x=tf.sets.set_intersection(a,b)`. The shape of this tensor is chosen based on the output of the function, not hardcoded or provided by placeholders.

Answer (score 3):

This question is already a year-old, so I believe you might have already found the answer you were looking for. But just in case other people will be looking for it I'll post it here.

The answer is pretty straightforward - use `tf.shape` method ([see documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/shape)) to evaluate the input tensor shape at session runtime.

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


input_data = np.zeros((4, 1, 2, 3), np.float32)

with tf.Graph().as_default():
    input_tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, None, None, 3))
    input_tensor_shape = tf.shape(input_tensor)

    with tf.Session() as session:
        shape = input_tensor_shape.eval({input_tensor: input_data}, session)
        print(shape)
```

Output:
[4 1 2 3]

Comment: Thanks! I do not remember what version of tf I was using at the time, but tf.shape was not available back then. It much easier now.